# Canvas where you can draw with red or blue color and background image

Tags: java, android, xml, drawing

I am trying to make an Android app where an image would always be in the background and when you touch above it, you can draw on it with red and it would be anti-aliased. Also, there would be a revert and a delete all drawings button.

Answer (score 1):

You may record every segments consisted of coordinates drawn by user, every time the ui refresh, clear the Canvas and redraw all the segments. For reverting, you remove the last segment, for deleting all you remove all segments.

Further more, if you need other operation, you may have to abstract an interface (named DrawingOperation for example) with undo/redo method.